# data-add-back-btn="true" doesn't work

Tags: jquery-mobile

The question is on the title. This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcolino/c2pUt/). This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Back button test</title>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="home" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <div data-role="header"><h1>header</h1></div>
        <div data-role="content">content</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JQM only adds a back-button on pages beyond first view. If you add another page with `data-add-back-btn="true"` it will show up:

```
<body>
<!-- -->
<div id="home" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>header</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        content <a href="#page2">page2</a>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="page2" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Page 2</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">Back-button visible</div>
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c2pUt/4/

---

Here's a snippet from jquery-mobile-1.2.0.js (starting on row 4800):

```
// Auto-add back btn on pages beyond first view
if (o.addBackBtn && role === "header" 
    && $(".ui-page").length > 1 
    && $page.jqmData("url") !== $.mobile.path.stripHash(location.hash) 
    && !leftbtn) {

    backBtn = $("<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='ui-btn-left' data-" + $.mobile.ns + "rel='back' data-" + $.mobile.ns + "icon='arrow-l'>" + o.backBtnText + "</a>")
    // If theme is provided, override default inheritance
    .attr("data-" + $.mobile.ns + "theme", o.backBtnTheme || thisTheme)
        .prependTo($this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed that "beyond first view"... So, if I need a back button on the first page (page is coming from a preceding external page), I will have to add it "by hand" ?

Comment: Also since jQuery mobile 1.4 this attribute should be added to [header, not page div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064843/data-add-back-btn-does-not-show-a-back-button)