# data-add-back-btn does not show a back button

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, button

I have a simple jQuery mobile site with three pages in it.
In every page's div I've added

```
data-add-back-btn="true"
```

Still on none of the pages (not even on the sub-pages) a back button appears.
Is there some trick to this?

Comment: Are you using JQM 1.4? If yes, add it to header div not page. Edit: pages should have header div even if you're using earlier version. Without a header div the button won't be generated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of jQuery Mobile 1.4, `data-add-back-btn="true"` should be added to header div not page div.

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```