# Page editor in Worklight Studio misplaces back button for jQuery Mobile 1.4.x

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I use recent Worklight Studio (6.2.0.01-20141002-2218). I use jQM 1.4.2 in hybrid project. When I enable "Add back button" to Header in property view of WYSIWYG editor nothing happens. The data-add-back-btn property is added to source code but back button is not rendered in preview and runtime. It was working before in Worklight 6.1 and jQM 1.3.x. Is it a bug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [data-add-back-btn does not show a back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064843/data-add-back-btn-does-not-show-a-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery Mobile 1.4.x the "back button" property must be added to header div instead of surrounding page div -- as discussed here: [data-add-back-btn does not show a back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064843/data-add-back-btn-does-not-show-a-back-button). Worklight plugin for Eclipse is not up-to-date regarding this feature and manual modification is required.

Comment: Thanks. This has been reported internally for investigation.