# How to get jQueryMobile Back button on Listview (Specific)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

So on mobile, I need a back button on this page: https://akj.sarabveer.me/keertan.php

Now, if you go to the page, and click on one of the cities, it opens a list, and I can't figure out how to get the back button on there.

I added `data-add-back-btn='true'`, but it's still not working.

Can someone view the source of the page and tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I had to put this code after jquery and before jquery-mobile

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
      $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
 });    
</script>
```

Comment: If you're using jQM 1.4, the code is different. Back button is an option of toolbar widget, not page. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20065246/1771795 For the global setting, replace `page` with `toolbar`.